# How to link variable and strings in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, hyperlink

I have a table called `cms_settings`. I name all the tabels with a prefix **cms_** so i created a variable **$dbpraefix="cms_"**
when i call the entry using "select value from $dbpraefix.settings" command, it failed to proceed.

i also tried defferent version. like "select from '.$dbpraefix.'settings etc. nothing works.

but if i use "select value from `cms_settings` instead, it works!. how can i fix this. thanks a lot

```
 <?PHP
    function getSetting($property){
    global $connection;
    $dbpraefix= "cms_";
    $sql= "SELECT value FROM $dbpraefix.settings WHERE property='$property'";
    $ergebnis= mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($ergebnis);
    return $row[0];
    }
?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: thanks tadman. im new in PHP so i still dont understand your advice. but ill come back to see this post again in 6 months :) i hope to understand it there.

Comment: There's a lot of dangerous people out there that will probe your site if this code is public and look for problems. Don't get caught out. Using placeholder values isn't hard and actually makes your code a lot cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: is this question still open? I don't see any accepted answer down there.

Answer (score 3):

Your query fails because in the string `"...$dbapraefix.settings..."` PHP doesn't realize that you want the `.` in the middle to be the string concatenation operator instead of a simple dot. As a result the string becomes `cms_.settings` instead of `cms_settings`

Change:

```
"SELECT value FROM $dbpraefix.settings WHERE property='$property'";
```

To

```
"SELECT value FROM {$dbpraefix}settings WHERE property='$property'";
```

Comment: `"SELECT value FROM {$dbpraefix}settings WHERE property='{$property}'";` I like being consistent when using brackets :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a dot between the prefix and table name, that's why it won't work.

Try this:  `" . $dbpraefix . "settings`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add a new parameter to your function so that when pass into the function it specify the table's name 
Eg : $table = "settings";

```
function getSetting($property,$table){
global $connection;
$table= "cms_".$table;
$sql= "SELECT value FROM $table WHERE property='$property'";
$ergebnis= mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($ergebnis);
return $row[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your query as below

```
$sql= "SELECT value FROM ".$dbpraefix."settings WHERE property='$property'";
```